# How to identify which SSIS package has failed when there are lot of pcakages called within each other

Tags: ssis, ssms

**Context**

I have a situation wherein there are lot of dtsx files and these individual packages are being called inside another package.

**Issue**

My package is failing and it is not giving proper error which can tell me which package has failed.
I am lost and not able to understand how to troubleshoot

**Question**
+How to identify which package has failed among many .dtsx file?
+Where should i look to find out the logs of the current run?
+to troubleshoot I would need to know which package failed and would like to understand how can i identify that?

Comment: That depends on how you are running your package. If you are running it of SSISDB, there's a standard report for the execution and it will allow you to drill down to the falling package and step.

Comment: To add to the comment from @Filburt, the catalog reports have a field called execution path, which shows the exact source of an error.  If you are executing this from the file system, you can enable logging in the package, but it will be pretty limited

Answer (score 0):

You should enable logging on your internal DTSX package and also parent DTSX package. If logging is enabled, your first step of identifying which package failed is very straight forward as that is information will be clearly mentioned. Then on the internal DTSX package, if you have logging enabled, you would also get further details. I typically use 2 levels of logging. One for the DTEXEC command which is running the DTSX package and second is internal DTSX level logging. Both these logs gives different level of information.